# Algorithm to find a $k$-partite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is there any algorithm which finds any $k$-partite graph of a given graph which is known to be a $k$-partite graph?

For example, you are given a graph $G$ with vertices $V$ and edges $E$, and you have to find $k$ *sets* of vertices which constitute a $k$-partite graph.

EDIT: The algorithm should be efficient enough. I think one naive solution exists but it would be an $O$(exponential).

Answer (score 1):

If we talking about finding the minimum value of $k$ such that the resulting graph is $k$-partite, then this is equivalent to finding the minimum number of colors needed to color the vertices of $G$ so no two adjacent vertices receive the same color, and that is a hard problem (for general $k$).

In fact for general graphs it hard to approximate; i.e., $G$ may be $k$-partite but still even for some $K >> k$ ($K$ could even be a factor of something like $n^{1-\epsilon}$ bigger!) there are no algorithms to color the graph even if allowed $K$ colors (so no two adjacent vertices get the same color).

If you know something about the graph though--planarity, degree bounds, ect, you likely can do much better. If the max degree of the graph is $k$ then of course $k+1$ colors suffices.